# Find length of a line segment in similar triangles problem.

Tags: geometry, solution-verification

Working on the book: Lang, Serge & Murrow, Gene. "Geometry - Second Edition" (p. 267)

> 3. If $\overline{EF} \parallel \overline{GH}$ in the diagrams below, find $|DE|$ in each case and explain your answers.

[image]

The solution given by the author is: $\frac{33}{4}$

I found that the following ratio holds,
$$
\frac{11}{7} = \frac{3+x}{x}
$$

because

- $m(\angle G) = m(\angle E)$ and $m(\angle H) = m(\angle F)$.
- Hence, $\triangle GDH$ and $\triangle EDF$ are similar.

(Using the theorem: "If two triangles have corresponding sides of same measure, then they are similar")

Doing algebraic operations, I arrived at:

$$
x = \frac{21}{4}
$$

What's the correct answer ?

Comment: where are the cases?

Comment: And it looks right , (it also goes by the name basic proportionality theorem)

Comment: Actually, *doing algebraic operations* yields $$x=\frac{21}4$$ Which is correct. You then have to add 3 in order to obtain $\lvert DE\rvert$.

Comment: Thank you, @Dr. Mathva. It was a typo. Correcting now.